# Reading and modifying the text from the text file in Java

Tags: java

I am have a project that need to modify some text in the text file.
Like  BB,BO,BR,BZ,CL,VE-BR
I need make it become BB,BO,BZ,CL,VE.
and HU, LT, LV, UA, PT-PT/AR become  HU, LT, LV, UA,/AR.

I have tried to type some code, however the code fail to loop and also,in this case.

IN/CI, GH, KE, NA, NG, SH, ZW /EE, HU, LT, LV, UA,/AR, BB

"AR, BB,BO,BR,BZ,CL, CO, CR, CW, DM, DO,VE-AR-BR-MX"

I want to delete the AR in second row, but it just delete the AR in first row.
I got no idea and seeking for helps.
Please

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tomy {
    static StringBuffer stringBufferOfData = new StringBuffer();
    static StringBuffer stringBufferOfData1 = stringBufferOfData;
    static String filename = null;
    static String input = null;
    static String s = "-";
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean fileRead = readFile();
        if (fileRead) {
            replacement();
            writeToFile();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static boolean readFile() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your files name and path i.e C:\\test.txt: ");
        filename = "C:\\test.txt";
        Scanner fileToRead = null;
        try {
            fileToRead = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            for (String line; fileToRead.hasNextLine()
                    && (line = fileToRead.nextLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println(line);
                stringBufferOfData.append(line).append("\r\n");
            }
            fileToRead.close();
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("The file " + filename + " could not be found! "+ ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            fileToRead.close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile() {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bufwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    filename));
            bufwriter.write(stringBufferOfData.toString());

            bufwriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {// if an exception occurs
            System.out.println("Error occured while attempting to write to file: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void replacement() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the contents of a line you would like to edit: ");

        String lineToEdit = sc.nextLine();

        int startIndex = stringBufferOfData.indexOf(lineToEdit);
        int endIndex = startIndex + lineToEdit.length() + 2;
        String getdata = stringBufferOfData.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);

        String data = " ";
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(getdata);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(data);
        String lineToEdit1 = sc1.nextLine();
        String replacementText1 = sc2.nextLine();
        int startIndex1 = stringBufferOfData.indexOf(lineToEdit1);
        int endIndex1 = startIndex1 + lineToEdit1.length() + 3;
        boolean test = lineToEdit.contains(getdata);
        boolean testh = lineToEdit.contains("-");
        System.out.println(startIndex);

        if (testh = true) {
            stringBufferOfData.replace(startIndex, endIndex, replacementText1);

            stringBufferOfData.replace(startIndex1, endIndex1 - 2,
                    replacementText1);

            System.out.println("Here is the new edited text:\n"
                    + stringBufferOfData);

        } else {
            System.out.println("nth" + stringBufferOfData);

            System.out.println(getdata);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove commented out code as I guess it's not significant.

Comment: Gave up trying to read your code intention, you could do with a better explanation of what you are trying to do. However, you shoud probably edit the lines as you read them from the input file and then write them directly to the output file. Reading the whole file in to memory for sequentail editing as you are doing imposes needless limits on the size of the file you can process, i.e. memory constraints.

Comment: I trying to find out the indexvalue of "-", and two letters which following the "-", then i tried to find out the relative row contains the two letters or not, if yes, delete it .

Comment: Okay had a bit of spare time after work, so I put something together for you. I am sure others can surely improve on it but it's something to get you started. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick method for you that I think does what you want, i.e. remove all occurrences of a token in a line, where that token is embedded in the line and is identified by a leading dash.

The method reads the file and writes it straight out to a file after editing for the token. This would allow you to process a huge file without worrying about about memory constraints.

You can simply rename the output file after a successful edit. I'll leave it up to you to work that out.

If you feel you really must use string buffers to do in memory management, then grab the logic for the line editing from my method and modify it to work with string buffers.

```
static void onePassReadEditWrite(final String inputFilePath, final String outputPath)
{
    // the input file
    Scanner inputScanner = null;
    // output file
    FileWriter outputWriter = null;

    try
    {
        // open the input file
        inputScanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFilePath));
        // open output file
        File outputFile = new File(outputPath);
        outputFile.createNewFile();
        outputWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);

        try
        {

            for (
                    String lineToEdit = inputScanner.nextLine();
                    /*
                     * NOTE: when this loop attempts to read beyond EOF it will throw the
                     * java.util.NoSuchElementException exception which is caught in the
                     * containing try/catch block.
                     * 
                     *  As such there is NO predicate required for this loop.
                    */;
                    lineToEdit = inputScanner.nextLine()
                )
                // scan all lines from input file
            {
                System.out.println("START LINE [" + lineToEdit + "]");

                // get position of dash in line
                int dashInLinePosition = lineToEdit.indexOf('-');

                while (dashInLinePosition != -1)
                    // this line has needs editing
                {

                    // split line on dash
                    String halfLeft = lineToEdit.substring(0, dashInLinePosition);
                    String halfRight = lineToEdit.substring(dashInLinePosition + 1);
                    // get token after dash that is to be removed from whole line
                    String tokenToRemove = halfRight.substring(0, 2);
                    // reconstruct line from the 2 halves without the dash
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(halfLeft);
                    sb.append(halfRight.substring(0));

                    lineToEdit = sb.toString();

                    // get position of first token in line
                    int tokenInLinePosition = lineToEdit.indexOf(tokenToRemove);

                    while (tokenInLinePosition != -1)
                        // do for all tokens in line
                    {
                        // split line around token to be removed
                        String partLeft = lineToEdit.substring(0, tokenInLinePosition);
                        String partRight = lineToEdit.substring(tokenInLinePosition + tokenToRemove.length());

                        if ((!partRight.isEmpty()) && (partRight.charAt(0) == ','))
                            // remove prefix comma from right part
                        {
                            partRight = partRight.substring(1);
                        }

                        // reconstruct line from the left and right parts
                        sb.setLength(0);
                        sb = new StringBuilder(partLeft);
                        sb.append(partRight);
                        lineToEdit = sb.toString();

                        // find next token to be removed from line
                        tokenInLinePosition = lineToEdit.indexOf(tokenToRemove);
                    }

                    // handle additional dashes in line
                    dashInLinePosition = lineToEdit.indexOf('-');
                }

                System.out.println("FINAL LINE [" + lineToEdit + "]");

                // write line to output file
                outputWriter.write(lineToEdit);
                outputWriter.write("\r\n");
            }

        }
        catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e)
            // end of scan
        {
        }
        finally
            // housekeeping
        {
            outputWriter.close();
            inputScanner.close();
        }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        inputScanner.close();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks dude, i am now trying my very best on it!! thanks!!

Comment: Your welcome, gimme a shout if you get stuck on it. BTW, accept the answer if it does the job for you please.

Comment: You are welcome. One day you will answer someone's question and the good will moves on.